# Cannot set 'inf' and '-inf' to be "NA" in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I'm having trouble setting pandas 'inf' and -'inf' to be "NA" in Jupyter Notebook. Here is the code:

> NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>         1 # If you want to consider 'inf' and '-inf' to be "NA" in computations:
>         2 
>   ----> 3 pandas.options.mode.use_inf_as_na = True
>
> NameError: name 'pandas' is not defined

Comment: That just looks like you haven't imported pandas?

Comment: I thought so at first as well and tried running it along with "import pandas as pd" as well as running it as it is in my question statement and both times I get the same message.

Comment: Change that line to `pd.options.mode.use_inf_as_na = True`. If you imported pandas as "pd" and not as "pandas", you can't reference pandas with "pandas".

Comment: Ok, did that and now I'm getting:    ` OptionError: 'You can only set the value of existing options'` Should I reset the kernel perhaps and start fresh?

Comment: I don't know. What does `print(pd.__version__)` show?

Comment: Wow, that's strange it's throwing ` AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute '_version_' `

Comment: @coldspeed, thank you so much for your help. I needed to upgrade my pandas package was the issue, all is running!